# Looking for example/explanation of why some basics results about variance/MGF are important

Tags: probability

My Professor had mentioned in my intro to probability course that there are some important properties about variance

let $X$ be a random variable, a and b constants,

then $$Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(x)$$

and most importantly,

$$M_{aX+b}=e^{tb}M_{x}(at)$$ ( referring to moment generating function).

However, as I work homework and problems and such I have never seemed to need to use either of these.

Can anyone provide any insight on these, are they really that important? and is there any basic problems that using these will help with?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Sure. If $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, find $a$ and $b$ such that $Y = aX+b$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.